# Concatenate ndarray along one axis

Tags: python, numpy

How can I concatenate an array at a given axis? 
So for the following array:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[4,5],[6,7]]])
```

I'm trying to obtain:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

I've tried using `np.concatenate` specifying an axis but without luck.

Comment: Simple reshape?

Comment: Is there a more generic way without having to specify the new dimensions?

Comment: `a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1)`?

Comment: Yes that does it @divakar thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way using `axis` here? `numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)`. It's what I was trying to do

Comment: What was the error?   What's `a1` and `a2`?

Comment: You can also do ` np.concatenate(a.swapaxes(1,0), axis=1)`